# Creating a message using the elements of 2 vectors in VBA

Tags: vba

With VBA I'm coding an userform that performs linear regression. I have a problem. I want to create a message composed of the elements of 2 vectors.

With an example it will be clearer:

I have 2 vectors:

> Vector A: `0.25; 0.50; -0.80`
>
> Vector B: `X^2; sqr(x); ln(x)`

I want to write a message "0.25X^2 + 0.50sqr(x) - 0.80ln(x)"

I need a dynamic solution because the number of elements of both vectors is not fixed. (For instance in one iteration both vectors can have 3 elements; in another they can have 4 elements).

How can I combine the elements of the 2 vectors in the message?

Comment: What controls the `+` or `-` joining the array elements?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
Function mergeArrays2String()

  Dim i, iUpbound, A, B, strret

  A = Array(0.25, 0.5, -0.8)
  B = Array("X^2", "sqr(x)", "ln(x)")
  '
  iUpbound = UBound(A)
  '
  strret = ""
  '
  For i = 0 To iUpbound
    '
    If (i > 0) Then
      If (A(i) > 0) Then
        strret = strret & "+"
      End If
    End If
    '
    strret = strret & A(i) & B(i)
    '
  Next
  '
  mergeArray2String = strret
  '
End Function
```